# Downloading Images From a Colorspace UDMA to Lightroom Running Under Mac OSX Lion

Tags: backup, file-transfer

Any advice on how to download images from this device (Hyperdrive Colorspace UDMA) to Lightroom in Mac appreciated. The images are present in the Colorspace device, but looks like the Mac is not recognizing the device when it is connected through a main USB, and as a consequence Lightroom is not able to access the images.

Comment: Given that your problem seems to be hardware related (and only consequentially related to Lightroom), I think this is better suited to SuperUser. I'm migrating this there, where you will hopefully get better answers.

Comment: If you open Disk Utility, and then plug in the device, can you see a new drive show up? if so, what does it say about it? Do you have another machine (Non OSX) you could try it on?

Answer (score 2):

The Colorspace Hypderdrive UDMA 2 has two USB ports - the one next to the power charging point is the one for connecting to a computer to download files

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link or a picture